# How to match 3 parameters including wildcard matches?

Tags: java

I want to define a blacklist filter that consists of a values. Let them be `a, b, c` in that order.

For quick lookup, I thought about concatenating them into a `Set<String>`, so I could quickly look up `blacklist.contains(a+b+c)`. Which works fine in general.

Problem: any but one of the 3 parameters **in the blacklist definition** may be wildcarted `*`. So the blacklist may eg contain:

```
OneTwoThree
*bc
```

As a result, the method call `isBlacklisted("One", "b", "c") = true`.
Sidenote: the method input parameter may of course not be wildcards, but only plain string words.

The question is: how could I write the lookup better as follows?

```
private Set<String> blacklist; //concatenation of 3 fields 'a+b+c'

private boolean isBlacklisted(String a, String b, String c) {
    return blacklist.contains(a+b+c)
        || blacklist.contains("*"+b+c)
        || blacklist.contains(a+"*"+c)
        || blacklist.contains(a+b+"*")
        || blacklist.contains("**"+c)
        || blacklist.contains(a+"**")
        || blacklist.contains("*"+b+"*");
}
```

How can I create quick filter that supports wildcards, without having to check against all possible concatenated wildcards like I did?

Comment: I don't understand. If `a` is a wildcard, what would be the difference between `a+b+c` and `"*"+b+c` ?

Comment: Let me rephrase: the blacklist may contain the parameter defined as wildcards. The input parameters are always plain strings and never wildcards.

Comment: If one item of your blacklist is a wildcard, why not just compare with the two other items ?

Comment: Should `isBlackListed` return `true` for the arguments `"OneTw", "oTh", "ree"`, if the `blackList` contained `"OneTwoThree"` (currently it does)

Comment: You're correct, that should not be the case. So probably I'd have to introduce an additional separator between the values during concatenation.

Comment: @membersound i've created [this mess](https://ideone.com/EvNHjd) based on [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55394215/5515060)

Comment: Query-by-Example (a technique) uses the same logic, but instead wild card a `null`.
It is used for instance with java JDBC, `DatabaseMetaData`, to query the database structure.

Answer (score 2):

When you write * you mean like "any string" ?

If yes - just use **regex**:

```
for (String blacklist : blackRegex)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(blackRegex);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()
    {
           return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

an example of *blackRegex* is **(someA)(someB).***

Use **.*** and not *** for any string, you can follow [java regex guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm).

Comment: Even beter would be to precompile the regexes and store them in `Set<Pattern>`

Comment: Absolutely, first wanted to give a solution

Comment: @membersound - did i answer your question ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Define a BlackListRule class :

```
class BlackListRule {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    BlackListRule(String a, String b, String c) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c;
    }

    public boolean matches(String a, String b, String c) {
        return ("*".equals(this.a) || this.a.equals(a))
             &&("*".equals(this.b) || this.b.equals(b))
             &&("*".equals(this.c) || this.c.equals(c));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(new char[][]{a.toCharArray(), b.toCharArray(), c.toCharArray()});
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof BlackListRule && ((BlackListRule)o).hashCode() == hashCode();
    }
}
```

```
private Set<BlackListRule> blacklist;
private boolean isBlacklisted(String a, String b, String c) {
    return blacklist.stream().anyMatch(rule -> rule.matches(a,b,c));
}
```

This is a minimal working example and you should definitely improve it, but you get the idea.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/bJq9cj).

Comment: @Lino didn't matter much in the context of that answer, but I've added them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all your suggestions, I ended as follows (assuming blacklist definition coming from db): for each "abc" blacklist tuple, I create a regex pattern. Those patterns are then concatenated with OR `|`.

```
private void init(SqlRowSet set) {
        Set<String> patterns = new HashSet<>();
        while (set.next()) {
            String a = set.getString(1);
            String b = set.getString(2);
            String c = set.getString(3);

            patterns.add(a + "/" + b + "/" + c);
        }

        regex = Pattern.compile(String.join("|", patterns));
}

private boolean isBlacklisted(String a, String b, String c) {
    return regex.matcher(a+"/"+b+"/"+c).matches();
}
```

Now I can create my blacklist with `a, b, .*` and match this with `isBlacklisted("a", "b", "anything") = true` for example.